# Ignore exceptions in a .NET application I don't have the source for

Tags: .net, windows, exception

A certain application I use throws exceptions sometimes. Clicking *Continue* allows me to keep using it and it works fine afterwards.

[image]

I don't have the source code for the application so fixing the error is out of the question. Is there any way I could tell the .NET runtime to ignore all errors in this application using, for example, a .config file?

Comment: Ugh, i hope not!

Comment: [try catch?](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

Comment: @HenrikWilshusen, you haven't even read the title.

Comment: My thoughts are wrapping code around your executable, I would expect you to be able to catch the exception. I have never tried myself. Have a look at: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb634348-797f-417e-8edf-d16577a88577/how-to-start-a-process-via-a-stream?forum=vbgeneral